# What does this overlapping ADC symbol in a block diagram mean?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, schematics, block-diagram

I am wondering what multiple overlapped ADC symbols in a block diagram mean.

[image: Overlapping ADC Symbols in a Block diagram]

My best guess is that it either represents multiple channels but I am not sure and each of the datasheets that I have seen do not provide a clear answer as to what the meaning is.

[image: Example 2]

Comment: Link the document that you saw the symbol. Likely that it is multiple ADCs.

Comment: Link doesn't work.$$ $$ **Always check your links!** $$ $$ Just photograph the page of the book and embed.

Comment: @Andyaka I updated the original post with a picture of the complete system. Not sure what happened with the link.

Comment: Andy do you have a link to a bank €£¥$

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 it's [here](https://www.schoolscapes.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Bank-Play-Panel-Image.jpg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read this as multiple ADCs being available and not as a multiplexed single ADC.

The [datasheet of the TSL2584TSV](https://ams.com/documents/20143/36005/TSL2584TSV_DS000352_4-00.pdf/b8becff6-3280-daed-ca51-97e04e7bce9a) supports this:

> Two integrating ADCs convert the photodiode currents into a digital
> output that represents the irradiance measured on each channel.

In my opinion a multiplexer is a different part in the signal chain and should be represented by an own block in front of the ADC. But that is only my opinion.

Not sure where you got the first image from, so I can't really comment on that one.

Answer (score 0):

Take Two: update

Since these Photo diodes act as current sources, only single integration is needed, so they are done in parallel.

- unlike a traditional multi-channel DMM* with dual slope = fixed time integration up then voltage dependant Time measuring integration down for best noise immunity of a noisy voltage.

The integration time is programmable in the counter registers.  The result is an 8bit result with optional gain control.  Except the highest gain is weird. Instead of putting the decoupling cap close to the chip, they want you to put it farther away as the trace inductance 0.5 to 1 nH/mm affects the gain error. To get so called gain=111x that is actually the farthest distance in the graph of L vs Distance to decoupling cap.   They average the gain of both channels VIS + IR or Ch 0&1

(116 + 106.5)/2= 111x gain

This could  be related to resonance in the IDC cap dump voltage error interacting with decoupling cap and low Ron low L series resonance on using Vdd for VRef for ADC conversion.

Although it’s possible they are doing something fancier and counting pico coulombs and dumping for each count while integration up to =≈2/3 second so single stage IDC converters x2ch

**So it is a dual ADC design but *anyway* they don’t really want to tell you how they do it.**

===============.

Initial guess

Consider it as two parallel integration 8 bit counters that  interpret this as a Dual Slope Integration ADC with a 2 port input analog MUX.

This could be a very useful E/W azimuth detector for a PV servo. But upon reading the specs, I see it is an CIE eye corrected filtered PD on 1 ch. and an IR filtered PD [photo diode] on the other.

The first block is a many channel MUX to ADC.